# Can every non-discrete topological group G be algebraically generated by a nowhere dense subset?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Is there somone help me to show that if this  problem have positive Answer   :

Problem :Can every non-discrete topological group G be algebraically gen-

erated by a nowhere dense subset ?

Thank you for any help .

Comment: Please take more effort in asking your questions. First, it is full of linguistic and spelling errors and other inconsistencies. Second, your labels are not appropriate, e.g. your question has nothing to do with proof theory (proof theory is not about asking for proofs), and little to do with normal subgroups.

Comment: I don't know where is the problem in my question ?

Comment: Apparently this was open as of 2001, according  to Problem 9 of http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Taras_Banakh/publication/221662575_Some_Open_Problems_in_Topological_Algebra/links/0fcfd50b52c10ec422000000.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much, i don't accross it yet .Just independent guess

Comment: Then it's unsolved until now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this paper on open problems in topological algebra](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Taras_Banakh/publication/221662575_Some_Open_Problems_in_Topological_Algebra/links/0fcfd50b52c10ec422000000.pdf), this is an open problem (it's listed as Problem 9 in particular).

> Problem 9 (Protasov). Can every topological group be algebraically generated by a
>   nowhere dense subset?
>
> Let us mention that each countable topological group is algebraically generated by
>   some closed discrete subset (see reference in [[13]](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FB%3AMATN.0000043466.45064.97)) while every left topological group is
>   algebraically generated by some subset with empty interior [[13]](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FB%3AMATN.0000043466.45064.97).

[13] in particular is from 2001.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the exact same paper mentioned by Nate Eldredge in his comment above.

Comment: @ToddTrimble It is exactly that.  He posted it to a comment as I was typing this together.

Comment: @Todd Trimble :ok what about the answer with nowhere not dense ? does it had a positive answer  ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Pardon my possible ignorance, but what do you mean by "nowhere not dense"?  Is that the same as "dense"?

Comment: yeah , for example :ensemble of Real number is nowhere but not dense ,if it's interesting  I edit my quesion

Comment: Then ,how a downvote for open problem ,confused !!!!?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik The entire group generates itself and is dense, in that case.  Your questions still seem confused, and are difficult to make sense of.  Possibly there is some meaningful question in what you want to say, but I am having trouble finding it.  The downvoter probably feels the same.  For example: the only google result for the entire phrase "not nowhere dense" is your own posts here on MO.  It did not exist before you.